# How do I configure the Luxon setting "throwOnInvalid" project wide?

Tags: typescript, luxon

I've upgraded Luxon, in a Typescript project, and ran into a breaking change in that `toISO()` now returns `string | null` rather than `string`. The documentation states that the setting `throwOnInvalid=true` reverts to the original behaviour.

I can fix each source file with:

```
import { DateTime, Settings } from "luxon";

Settings.throwOnInvalid = true;
declare module 'luxon' {
  interface TSSettings {
    throwOnInvalid: true;
  }
}

const now: string = DateTime.now().toISO();
```

Rather than adding several lines of configuration to every source file, is there a way to configure this setting project wide?

Answer (score 2):

You need to merge module declarations.
Create a declaration file like `global.d.ts`.
Add the following to satisfy typescript:

```
export {}
declare module 'luxon' {
  interface TSSettings {
    throwOnInvalid: true
  }
}
```

And then initialise once at an appropriate place in your code with:

```
Settings.throwOnInvalid = true
```

Comment: What is an "appropriate place"?